# AWS S3 Gitpull from Bitbucket and CodePipeline

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I'm setting a continuous delivery system using Bitbucket, Jenkins, and AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I've got an issue where it appears the Bitbucket integration I've setup following this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-git-with-aws-codepipeline/) is only building the master branch.  Without direct support in Code Pipeline, like Github and AWS CodeCommit, I'm not sure how to setup builds with specific branches such as develop or release candidate branches.

Is it possible to indicate which branch should be built in CodePipeline from an S3 zip of the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodePipeline now has direct Bitbucket cloud support :)

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-atlassian-bitbucket-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace "master" in s3://git-to-codepipeline-us-east-1/v1.0/GitPullS3.zip with your branch. And using your new GitPullS3.zip in your Lambda function instead of the original one.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info?  Are you referring to the Lambda?  My understanding is that the GitPull Lambda uses SSH to pull a copy of the repo into S3.  By default this would be the master branch. To take advantage of CodePipeline I'd like to deploy develop, master, and a hotfix branch to separate environments.

Comment: I ended up going with a solution along these lines. I modified the python script to grab the destination branch from the Bitbucket json sent by the webhook.  The Lambda then pulls to specific S3 buckets. I then created two separate pipelines for 'develop' and 'master' listening for triggers from the respective S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to replace the string "master" in lambda_function.py file in the zip found at s3://git-to-codepipeline-us-east-1/v1.0/GitPullS3.zip (use correct bucket based on the region you are working on) , and create a new zip and upload it to S3. And, then use this new S3 file in your GitPull lambda function (you can update the CloudFormation stack to use your new S3 file in the GitPull Lambda function).

Comment: I looked into this option and I think it is doable.  However, I don't think it is the correct approach.  Example: the Lambda:GitPull can now checkout 'develop' -> CodePipeline:Build stage is only able to build 'develop'.  I think the proper approach is to have the CodePipeline:Build stage switch branches as required since it is pulling the entire repo initially and updating based on changes I *think* it should have the branch info already.